# 64bit VTK library has no response to mouse and keyboard events

Tags: qt, events, keyboard, mouse, vtk

My 64bit VTK library was compiled with MinGW-w64, and I found the following code has no response to mouse and keyboard events while it works under 32bit VTK library:

```
#include <vtkAutoInit.h>
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkInteractionStyle)
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingFreeType)
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL)
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL)

#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkSphereSource.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource> sphere =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource>::New();
  sphere->Update();

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
  mapper->SetInputConnection(sphere->GetOutputPort());

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
  actor->SetMapper(mapper);

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> ren =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
  ren->AddActor(actor);

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> win =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
  win->AddRenderer(ren);

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> iren =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
  iren->SetRenderWindow(win);

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera> trackball =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera>::New();
  iren->SetInteractorStyle(trackball);


  win->Render();
  iren->Start();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I use Qt Creator to generate the program. However, if I use QVTKWidget as a window, the following code works fine:

```
#include <vtkAutoInit.h>
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkInteractionStyle)
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingFreeType)
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL)
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL)

#include <QApplication>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkSphereSource.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.h>

// use QVTKWidget as a window
#include <QVTKWidget.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QVTKWidget widget;
  widget.resize(800, 600);

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource> sphere =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource>::New();
  sphere->Update();

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
  mapper->SetInputConnection(sphere->GetOutputPort());

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
  actor->SetMapper(mapper);

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> ren =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
  ren->AddActor(actor);

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> win =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
  win->AddRenderer(ren);

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> iren =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
  iren->SetRenderWindow(win);

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera> trackball =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera>::New();
  iren->SetInteractorStyle(trackball);


  win->Render();
  //iren->Start();

  widget.SetRenderWindow(win);
  widget.show();
  app.exec();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Would anyone like to tell me why would this happen?

Comment: When it works with Qt, but it does not without... why the qt flag? Not a Qt problem. ;-)

Comment: Yes, it is not a Qt problem, I think it must be a problem compiling VTK as a 64-bit version with 64-bit MinGW compiler. But why would this happen? Anyone encounter such a case?